# How to fill an image inside my svg circles in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

This is my piece of code filling circles in my svg.

```
   var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                 .attr("width", 1000)
                             .attr("height", 1000);
    var circles = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
                      .data(nodes)
                      .enter()
                      .append("circle");

     var circleAttributes = circles
                   .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x_axis; })
                   .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y_axis; })
                   .attr("r", function (d) { return d.radius; })
                   .attr('fill', 'green')
```

But instead of filling green color inside my circles, I want to fill different image inside each circles where the url is in my json data. I've been trying to use .attr('fill', url(function(d) {return d.url})) but it does not work. I am new to d3 and can anyone help me solving this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine you have a dataset like this:

```
data = [{
  posx: 100,
  posy: 100,
  img: "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-round-system/512/android-128.png",

}, {
  posx: 200,
  posy: 200,

  img: "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-set/24/Reverbnation-128.png"
}, {
  posx: 300,
  posy: 300,

  img: "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-pictures/100/male3-128.png"
}]
```

Make defs like this in svg like this:

```
var defs = svg.append('svg:defs');
```

Iterate over all the data and make as many defs with image and circle.
Inside circles's fill pass the def's id like this `.style("fill", "url(#grump_avatar" + i + ")");`

```
data.forEach(function(d, i) {
  defs.append("svg:pattern")
    .attr("id", "grump_avatar" + i)
    .attr("width", config.avatar_size) 
    .attr("height", config.avatar_size)
    .attr("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
    .append("svg:image")
    .attr("xlink:href", d.img)
    .attr("width", config.avatar_size)
    .attr("height", config.avatar_size)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0);

  var circle = svg.append("circle")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + d.posx + "," + d.posy + ")")
    .attr("cx", config.avatar_size / 2)
    .attr("cy", config.avatar_size / 2)
    .attr("r", config.avatar_size / 2)
    .style("fill", "#fff")
    .style("fill", "url(#grump_avatar" + i + ")");

})
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4sQSQ0ChpJon4OwY2Ag1?p=preview)

Inspired from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25881186/d3-fill-shape-with-image-using-pattern)

Answer (score 5):

Creating pattern from image uses too much of memory and using multiple images will create a serious performance issue. So to avoid that we can use clip-path over image.

Like this:

```
var config = {
  "avatar_size": 100
}

var body = d3.select("body");
var svg = body.append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 500);

var defs = svg.append('svg:defs');

data = [{
  posx: 100,
  posy: 100,
  img: "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-and-data/500/pencil-gear-128.png",
}, {
  posx: 200,
  posy: 200,
  img: "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-and-data/500/gear-clock-128.png"
}, {
  posx: 300,
  posy: 300,
  img: "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-and-data/500/magnifier-data-128.png"
}];


svg .append('clipPath')
   .attr('id','clipObj')  
        .append('circle')
         .attr('cx',config.avatar_size/2)
          .attr('cy',config.avatar_size/2)
         .attr('r',config.avatar_size/2);

data.forEach(function(d,i){
  svg.append('image')
     .attr('xlink:href',d.img)
     .attr('width',config.avatar_size)
     .attr('height',config.avatar_size)
 .attr('transform','translate('+parseInt(d.posx+config.avatar_size/2)+','+parseInt(d.posy+config.avatar_size/2)+')')
     .attr('clip-path','url(#clipObj)');
});
```

Also we can easily replace the clipping area with new one as we want.
Here is the link of Code pen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VagxKp?editors=0010

Comment: in order to use `rect` as clipPath, use `width` and `height` instead of `cx`, `cx`, `r`.