# D3 Image SVG not showing

Tags: image, svg, d3.js

I want to make a image fill inside svg circle, but avoid the "pattern" mode like in this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25881186/d3-fill-shape-with-image-using-pattern) because of the circular positioning.

So I tried this:

```
var defs = group
 .append('svg:defs')

defs
 .append("svg:image")
 .attr("id", "chara_avatar")
 .attr("xlink:href", imglink)
 .attr("width", 3*rad)
 .attr("height", 2*rad)
 .attr('x', (d,i)=>{ //same x position as the circle
   let x = (r * Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 * (i * 36) / 360)) + cx
   return x-rad;
   })
 .attr('y',(d,i)=>{ //same y position as the circle
   let y = (r * Math.cos(Math.PI * 2 * (i * 36) / 360)) + cy
   return y-rad;
   });
```

And directly use with `"url('#chara_avatar')"` :

```
var graphic = group
 .append('circle')
 .attr('cx', (d,i)=>{
   let x = (r * Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 * (i * 36) / 360)) + cx
   return x;
  })
 .attr('cy',(d,i)=>{
   let y = (r * Math.cos(Math.PI * 2 * (i * 36) / 360)) + cy
   return y;
  })
 .attr('r',rad)
 .style('fill', (d)=> {
   let init = d.val;
   if(init==1) {
     return "url(#chara_avatar)" // <------- called the url for fill
   } else if (init==0) {
     return 'black'
   }
   })
 .style('stroke', 'black')
 .style('stroke-width', '3px')
 .style('cursor',(d)=> {
   let init = d.val;
   if (init==1) {
     return 'pointer'
   }
  })
```

But it turns out like this:
[image: Screenshot 1]

- I got the position right, the element are there, but it doesn't show up.
- The image tag AFAIK was properly put, but it shows only `href` not `xlink:href` even I write `'xlink:href'`

If I change `defs` to `group` (append the image directly to group), it works and place the image above the circle, & I dont know how to clip it. I already used ClipPath but not working.

[image: Screenshot 2]

Full code example: [Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/louislugas/pen/PoJVEZw)

*UPDATE*:

> **Didn't find any good answer here, and I choose appending divs than svgs, it works with a bit more lines**

Comment: you can't fill a shape with an image directly, you have to fill it with a pattern that contains an image.

Comment: You have the same `<image id="chara_avatar"` over and over. Id-s must be unic.

Comment: What did you use to append divs? <foreignObject>?

Comment: @Shreshth yes I've been desperate so I use divs :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved by adding as many SVG `<image>` elements in appropriate location as circles needed.

Then you would use `<clipPath>` with `<circle>` inside them and "link" each circular clipPath to each `<image>`. Again the location of each circle should match the image it has to clip.

Attached a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/shreshthmohan/pen/vYePNmj)

Snippet:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1100 600" style="background-color: steelblue;">

  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-circle-0">
      <circle r="50" cx="100" cy="100"></circle>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>


  <image  href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1490730141103-6cac27aaab94?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=2070&amp;q=80" x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" style="clip-path: url(#clip-circle-0)"></image>


</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! I never think about that possibility

Comment: You're welcome. For more, this article has a ton of useful info about clip paths: https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-svg-clipping/

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a pattern you can instead clip the image with the circle.

In the next example I'm using a circle and an image both centered around the point x=0,y=0.
Next I'm translating the image to the desired position, the one that in your code is the center of the circle. The image is clipped with the circle.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1100 600" style="background-color: steelblue;">

  <defs>
    <image id="chara_avatar" xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1490730141103-6cac27aaab94?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=2070&amp;q=80" width="189.63000000000002" height="126.42000000000002" x="-94.185" y="-63.21"></image>
    <clipPath id="cp">
      <circle id="c" r="63.21000000000001" style="fill:red; stroke: black; stroke-width: 3px; cursor: pointer;"></circle>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>


    <use transform="translate(509,526.75)" xlink:href="#chara_avatar" clip-path="url(#cp)"></use>
    <use transform="translate(641.6925207050258,483.6355864801444)" xlink:href="#chara_avatar" clip-path="url(#cp)"></use>


</svg>
```

You can do the same for every circle.

Comment: I really like this solution, though only worried about the deprecated `xlink:href` attribute. Though I tried using the same approach with `href` on <use> and it did not work!